# Tab Bar Content Box Overhangs Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is for a tab box I've created. I'm having an issue with the content in the tab box hanging over the bottom of the page.  I believe the fix would be added in the .tab-content div, but can't think of anything besides margin which isn't working.  Is there an easy fix for this?

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var activeTabIndex = -1;
var tabNames = ["tab1","tab2","tab3"];

$(".tab-menu > li").click(function(e){
    for(var i=0;i<tabNames.length;i++) {
        if(e.target.id == tabNames[i]) {
            activeTabIndex = i;
        } else {
            $("#"+tabNames[i]).removeClass("active");
            $("#"+tabNames[i]+"-tab").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
    $("#"+tabNames[activeTabIndex]+"-tab").fadeIn();
    $("#"+tabNames[activeTabIndex]).addClass("active");
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
body{
        background: #fff;
        margin:0;
        }
        .clear{
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        }
        a {
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        #tab-container{
        font-family: Arial,  Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height:16px;
        margin: 1em auto;
        width: 700px;
        border:0px solid #ccc;
        height:28px;
        background:#e1eff8;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:13px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 2px #dadada;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset  0 -20px 2px #dadada;
        box-shadow: inset 0-5px 10px #dadada;
        border-top-left-radius:10px;
        border-top-right-radius:10px;
        }
        #tab-container ul{
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        }
        #tab-container ul.tab-menu li{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #ddc;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-width: 1px;
        color: #999;
        cursor: default;
        height: 14px;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        #tab-container ul.tab-menu li.active{
        background: #fff;
        color: #0088CC;
        height: 15px;
        border-bottom: 0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, white 10%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 10%, from(#ebebeb), to(white));
        }
        .tab-top-border {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d0ccc9;
        }
        .tab-content{
        margin: auto;
        background: #efefef;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddc;
        border-top-style: none;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-size: 11px;
        display: none;
        height: auto;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 2px #dadada;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset  0 -2px 2px #dadada;
        border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
        }
        #tab-container div.active{
        display: block;
        }
        .tab-content h1{
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 28px;
        font-size: 22px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="tab-container">
    <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li id="tab1" class="active">Tab 1</li>
        <li id="tab2">Tab 2</li>
        <li id="tab3">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="tab-top-border"></div>
    <div id="tab1-tab" class="tab-content active">
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2-tab" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3-tab" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab 3 content</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/16orqy9c/1/

I know it's kind of hard to tell from the fiddle, but like I said, the content hangs over the bottom of the page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: on your jsfiddle, on the left side, add "jQuery" and update your jsfiddle link

Comment: and I don't see any thing "hangs over" by that you mean outside of the blue container box? looks good on my end

Comment: Yeah, you won't see it in the fiddle, but it hangs out of the page container it is inside of.  Ends up on top of the website footer.  I think I have solved the problem by deleting the height:28px; line out of the #tab-container div.  Continuing to mess with it to see if it is fixed.

Comment: like @wlin said... I don't see any issues, and I'm not really sure what you mean by "hanging over the bottom of the page".